# Lazy foldRight early termination confusion

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, fold

While going though [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I came across the following code snippet:

```
def foldRight[A](z: => B)(f: (A,=>B) => B):B = uncons match {
  case Some((h,t)) => f(h,t.foldRight(z)(f))
  case None => z 
}
```

The authors then go ahead and state the following:

> This looks very similar to the foldRight we wrote for List, but
>   notice how our combining function, f, is non-strict in its second
>   parameter. If f chooses not to evaluate its second parameter, this
>   terminates the traversal early. We can see this by using foldRight to
>   implement exists, which checks to see if any value in the Stream
>   matches a given predicate.

Then the author states the following:

```
def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean =
  foldRight(false)((a, b) => p(a) || b)
```

My question is how does the combining function f causes early termination in the exists method? I don't think I was able to understand how that happens from the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `f(h,t.foldRight(z)(f))`, the first argument provided to `f` is `h`, the second argument is `t.foldRight(z)(f)`. The way `foldRight` is defined is that the second argument of its `f` argument is a by-name argument which will not be evaluated until needed (and will be evaluated everytime it is needed). So in `f: (A, =>B) => B`, the first argument of type `A` is a normal argument, but the second one of type `B` is a by-name argument.

So pretend you defined `f` like this:

```
f(a: A, b: => Boolean): Boolean = predicate(a) || b
```

If `predicate(a)` is true then `b` is never needed and will never be evaluated. That is the way the *or* operator works.

So say for `exists` applied to some `Stream`. For the **first** element to be uncons-ed that will **exist** (where `p(h)` is true) this code:

```
uncons match {
  case Some((h,t)) => f(h,t.foldRight(z)(f))
  case None => z 
}
```

Is the same as this code (we assume we have a non-empty stream, so we can remove the second case):

```
f(h,t.foldRight(z)(f))
```

Which is then equivalent to (expanding `f`):

```
p(h) || t.foldRight(z)(f)
```

But `p(h)` is true so:

```
true || t.foldRight(z)(f)
```

And that's the same as just `true` and no need to continue calling `foldRight`, so early termination happens!